# accessing variable outside for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, scope

how to access a string assigned some value in a for loop, outside the for loop
i may provide you with the code for thy convenience

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < yourlist.Count; i++)
    {
        String str=(yourlist[i].ToString() + ",");
    }

    String str1 = (str).Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

the error displayed is

> The name 'str' does not exist in the current context

Comment: you may want to add a tag 'variable scoping' or the like.  Or google for that term.

Answer (score 9):

The scope of the variable does not extend to outside the loop. If you want to access its value, you need to save it to another variable with a greater scope, like this:

```
string str;
for (Int32 i = 0; i < yourlist.Count; i++)
{
    str=(yourlist[i].ToString() + ",");
}

String str1 = (str).Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

However, what you are trying to do can be simply done as:

```
var str1 = string.Join(",", yourlist.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Either you don't need the `Select` or you also need a `ToArray()`.

Comment: @SLaks: why `or`? Doesn't he need both `Select()` and `ToArray()`?

Comment: @zerkms: In .Net 3.5, `Join` only takes an array.  In .Net 4.0, it also takes a `IEnumerable<T>` and calls `ToString()` for you.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a variable inside a `for` loop (or any other scope), it doesn't exist outside of that scope.
You need to declare the variable outside of the loop.

Note that this won't do what you want it to do, since you aren't appending the string.
Instead, you should use a StringBuilder.
You can make it somewhat simpler by only appending `", "` if `i > 0`.

In .Net 4.0, you can replace your entire loop with a [new overload of `String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx):

```
string str1 = String.Join(", ", yourlist);
```

Before .Net 4.0, you can replace it with

```
string str1 = String.Join(", ", yourlist.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: then what would I have to store the result

Comment: my list is giving 4 integers value here,can it still replace the last comma by itself??

Comment: SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select id,name from plugins where id =(" + str1 + ")" , con);

Comment: i need to use the value in the above query but it is displaying error that syntax error near ","
can somebody explain why
:(

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = string.Empty;

for (Int32 i = 0; i < yourlist.Count; i++)
{
    str=(yourlist[i].ToString() + ",");
}

String str1 = (str).Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

Also you may want to store the result back to str variable

```
 str = (str).Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

In such case you dont need to declare one more variable

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
 String str = "";

 for (Int32 i = 0; i < yourlist.Count; i++)   
   {   
      str =(yourlist[i].ToString() + ","); 
   }   
 String str1 = (str).Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable str before the loop starts.because the variable str declared inside the for loop goes out of scope and hence is an error in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str;
for (int i = 0; i < yourlist.Count; i++)
{
    str = (yourlist[i].ToString() + ",");
}
str1 = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

But the better way to write this code is:

```
str1 = string.Join(",", yourlist);
```

Although "str" and "str1" are really bad names for variables. They don't mean anything. A variable name should have a clue to what this variable stores, and not to its datatype.

Answer (score 0):

String.Join is what you want. You don't have to use a loop.

```
String.Join(",", yourlist);
```

Comment: You mean `String.Join`.  Also, that will only work in .Net 4.0.  See my answer.