# Cant use the value out of the while loop

Tags: c#, validation, variables, console-application

I want to validate if they enter numbers and then after that validate if the number is between 20 - 50 and then calculate the sum of all positive numbers before that.

```
int i, sum = 0;

var valid = false;
while (!valid)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 20 and 50(50 is included)");
    Console.WriteLine("Only Numbers will be accepted");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

    var val = Console.ReadLine();
    valid = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val) &&
        val.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
    Console.WriteLine(val + " is what you entered");
}

Int16 num = int.Parse(val);
if (num > 20 && num <= 50)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    Console.WriteLine("Sum of all numbers before "+ Convert.ToString(num) + " is " + Convert.ToString(sum));

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
}
else
{

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("Number is not within the limits of 20-50!!!");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing variable outside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639445/accessing-variable-outside-for-loop)

Comment: not really because I'm trying to find a way to get the interger value from the variable but it's inside the loop

Comment: So how does that not answer your question? It is literally asking about accessing a variable outside of a loop. If you read the accepted answer, it has the solution to your problem.

Comment: will it work the same if I put my var and integer variables instead of their string variables?

Comment: @CameronGanesh - try it...

Comment: okay i will try it

Comment: Yes... you're not supposed to take the code from the post I linked literally. You need to learn to adapt existing solutions to your needs. Obviously use the type that you require.

Comment: okay thank you for all the help

Comment: As a side note, you should use `short` instead of `Int16`. That is the preferred/far more common practice.

Comment: Okay, I will. I am just a beginner coder and It really helps. Thank you

Comment: @CodeStranger That is highly subjective. I always use the CLR type names; it makes the colour on all types in my code in the IDE look the same.

Comment: I was making it look like the computer one color then typing is a different one and those spaces a different

Comment: @Nyerguds - Sure it is, so perhaps saying "preferred" was a poor statement. Though I would say that the C#-specific names are the far more common of the 2 options (I've never worked at a place that preferred CLR type names, and most actually explicitly disallowed them in their coding standards). At the very least, it's important to be consistent. For example, OP uses plain `int` on line 1, and even does `int.Parse` to assign to the `Int16`. Microsoft also primarily use the C# naming in examples in the docs, and much of the reference source.

Comment: @CodeStranger okay, but, int.parse makes no sense since it's a static function from the `Int32 `class :-\

Comment: @Nyerguds - yes, but I'm saying that if OP were staying consistent, they would've done `Int16 num = Int32.Parse(val);` for the current code. But even then, it's going to a `short`/`Int16` anyway so it "should" be either `Int16.Parse()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First: Have a look at this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum** for the summation.

**Second: The code:**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var valid = false;

            while (!valid)
            {
                var line = Console.ReadLine();

                if(Int16.TryParse(line, out var numericValue))
                {
                    if(numericValue >= 20 && numericValue <= 50)
                    {
                        int sum = Calculate(numericValue);
                        valid = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // It was not a number or outsinde the range of Int16
                }
            }
        }

        private static int Calculate(int num)
        {
            return (num * (num + 1) / 2);
        }
```

Int16.TryParse checks softly wether the value from Console.ReadLine() is a numeric in the range of Int16 or not. I use the Gauss Sum in Calculate() for the summation.

Also have a look at class and object variables.

Comment: Thank you very much it really helps

Comment: it is saying var and numericValue do not exist in this context. What can I do about that

Comment: Is the line of code exactly like this: if( Int16.TryParse(line, out var numericValue)) { ... } if yes: you can remove this line and replace it with: short numericValue = 0;   if(Int16.TryParse(line, out numericValue)) {...}  - But to copy everything is not the way to learn programing.

Comment: `out var numericValue` - is that a more recent addition to c#? I know that doesn't work in .Net 3.5

Comment: Yah its exactly like that. I know coping isn't learning but I've spent 2 days on this project nonstop and I just want to submit and get some sleep. (crying face)